# Program Preferences no longer recognizes Desktop webmail

Tags: email, preferences

Until today, I had desktop-webmail as my preferred e-mail client. Today, I clicked on an e-mail link, and up popped an Evolution window.

I do not know of any changes that I deliberately made to desktop-webmail or the preferred applications settings.

When I opened the preferred applications settings, I did not have the option to select desktop-webmail, nor did I have custom command entries available for either the web browser or the e-mail client settings, although I did still have the custom command entry available for other program preferences.

1) Does this indicate some deeper misconfiguration in my system that I need to try to fix?

2) What is the command line for resetting my default e-mail client?

Answer (score 2):

I made a new `desktop-webmail` release and uploaded new packages for Ubuntu to my [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~asac/+archive/ppa).